# Why CustomProjectAggregationOperation Not working in SpringMongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-mongo

I trying the following query in spring onto the template, that query works in Mongoserver, but when I using the query in the SpringMongo template, the filter does not work, it gets all date, instead of filters date. If anyone knows this issue. pls, help me out this.

The Native Mongo Query:-

```
db.Task_Status.aggregate([{
{"$addFields":{"timeDiff": { $floor: { $divide: [ { $subtract:[ new Date() , "$currenttime" ] } , 60000 ] }  } }},
{$match:{$and:[{"timeDiff":{"$lt": 12}}]}} }]);
```

The Spring MongoTempalte java Code:

```
String nativeFilterQuery = "{\"$addFields\":{\"timeDiff\": { $floor: { $divide: [ { $subtract:[ new Date() , \"$currenttime\" ] } , 60000 ] }  } }},{$match:{$and:[{\"timeDiff\":{\"$lt\": 12}}]}}";
List<TaskStatus> amTaskLists = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperations = new ArrayList<>();
        if (StringUtility.isNotNullOrEmpty(nativeFilterQuery)) {
            aggregationOperations.add(new CustomProjectAggregationOperation(nativeFilterQuery));
        }
        TypedAggregation<TaskStatus> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(TaskStatus.class, aggregationOperations);
        AggregationResults result = execute(aggregation, TaskStatus.class);
        amTaskLists = result.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: What versions of MongoDB and Spring are you using? It is much easier if you use the pipeline `AggregationOperations` _project_ and _match_. See the documentation at: [Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation Framework Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation).

Comment: You need to convert JSON stages into `AggregationOperation`s individually. try to log `aggregation.toString()` and check what pipeline has been defined.

Comment: @prasad_ thanks for your reponse, i am using Spring  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>, and 3.6 mongo db ,

Answer (score 0):

When I split the query and Run like following its works

```
String queryOne = "{\"$addFields\":{\"timeDiff\": { $floor: { $divide: [ { $subtract:[ new Date() , \"$currenttime\" ] } , 60000 ] }  } }}";
            String queryTwo = "{$match:{$and:[{\"timeDiff\":{\"$lt\": 12}}]}}";
            List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperations = new ArrayList<>();
            if (StringUtility.isNotNullOrEmpty(queryOne)) {
                aggregationOperations.add(new CustomProjectAggregationOperation(queryOne));
            }
            if (StringUtility.isNotNullOrEmpty(queryTwo)) {
                aggregationOperations.add(new CustomProjectAggregationOperation(queryTwo));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AggregationOperation` for performing different aggregation in springmongo,but `$addFields` not support till 3.2 version  for that use `DBObject` for creating query.

For example i used `addFields` to add score in textcriria my `AggregationOperation` is:

```java
AggregationOperation score = new AggregationOperation() {
    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
        return new BasicDBObject(
            "$addFields", 
            new BasicDBObject("score", new BasicDBObject("$meta","textScore"))
        );
    } 
};
```

So you can use in your way to find timeDiff and also create match function and you can use like:

```java
List<AggregationOperation> dataListopeartion = new ArrayList<>();
MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("timeDiff").lte(12));
dataListopeartion.add(match);
dataListopeartion.add(score);   //your timeDiff  query with AggregationOperation
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(dataListopeartion);
AggregationResults<TaskStatus> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Task_Status,TaskStatus.class);
ListMongoWrapper<TaskStatus> mongoWrapper = groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

You can also refer following answer of SO for better understanding:

- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53897516/9450155), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312068/9450155)